# C int memory storage. Least signinficant vs most significant bits?

Tags: c, memory, int, uint8t, uint16

I'd expect the following combination of two `uint8_t` (0x00 and 0x01) into one `uint16_t` to give me a value of 0x0001, when I combine them consecutively in memory. Instead I obtain 0x0100 = 256, which I'm surprised of.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main(void){

    uint8_t u1 = 0x00, u2 = 0x01;
    uint8_t ut[2] = {u1, u2};
    uint16_t *mem16 = (uint16_t*) ut;

    printf("mem16 = %d\n", *mem16);

    return 0;
}
```

Could anyone explain me what I've missed in my current understanding of C memory?
Thank you! :-)

Comment: Google _endianess_.

Comment: Depends on the CPU

Comment: And then study [What is the strict aliasing rule?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/98650/what-is-the-strict-aliasing-rule)

Comment: Google *vararg* + defaul promotion.

Comment: In x86 systems the 16 bit words (and all type of integers) are in LITTLE ENDIAN order byte. The byte 0 (the first) is the low order, the byte N (N=1 in this case) is the high order byte.

Comment: Thank you for all your answers and comments! I understand better now :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is called `endianess`.

Most system nowadays use little endian. In this system first is stored the least significant byte. So the 0x0100 is stored (assuming 2 bytes representation) as `{0x00, 0x01}` exactly as in your case

Answer (score -2):

ut[0] is inserted on LSB of mem16 , and ut[1] on MSB.

Comment: This does not really explain what the OP is missing, does it?